# WPF application OnExit event

Tags: c#, wpf, function-exit

I have a WPF application with a main Window.

In App.xaml.cs, in the OnExit event, I would like to use a method from my MainWindow code behind...

```
public partial class App
{
    private MainWindow _mainWindow;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
         _mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        _mainWindow.Show();


    }

    protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        _mainWindow.DoSomething();
    }

}
```

The method :

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    myController.Function(
       (sender, e) =>
       {

        },

       (sender, e) =>
        {

        }
        );
 }
```

But I put a breakpoint on the "_mainWindow.DoSomething();" and when I press f11, it doesn't enter into the function and the function does nothing... Am I missing something ?

I'm a beginner, is it possible to do what I need ?

EDIT : post edited

Comment: what is myController?

Comment: It's a instance of a class I have in the MainWindow : "public myController mycontroller;" , "printerController = new myController(); and I need to use this instance from the "OnExit" event. I also tried to use the "Closed" Event of the MainWindow, but when I close the window, the applications closes and the event is not fired...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared your _mainWindow as the Window class. The Window class does not have a DoSomething function. 
Change the class of _mainWindow to MainWindow and it should work.

```
 public partial class App
{
    private MainWindow _mainWindow;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Oh... thanks. The function is now accessible. But I put a breakpoint on the "_mainWindow.DoSomething();" and when I press f11, it doesn't enter into the function and the function does nothing... Am I missing something ?

Comment: i used your code and only changed what i showed here and changed DoSomething to print something to console ( Console.WriteLine("DoSomething"); ) and it does work for me. I guess you're missing something but i cannot tell what. Maybe post more code?

Answer (score 0):

your app.cs shoule look like

```
 public partial class App : Application
{
    private MainWindow _mainwindow;

    public MainWindow mainwindow
    {
        get { return _mainwindow??(_mainwindow=new MainWindow()); }
        set { _mainwindow = value; }
    }
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        _mainwindow.Show();
    }
    protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        _mainwindow.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post (the function does nothing)

Answer (score 0):

Class Window does not have the member DoSomething, class MainWindow does (derived from Window).

Either change

```
private Window _mainWindow;
```

to

```
private MainWindow _mainWindow;
```

or cast your method call like this

```
((MainWindow)_mainWindow).DoSomething();
```